# how to show this part only in the single post page?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, conditional-tags

I have this part in my index-meta.php file :

```
                        <ul>

                            <li class="Source"><a>source:</a></li>
                              <ul class="Source-Link">
                                <li><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'source-link', true); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'source', true); ?></a></li>
                              </ul>

                        </ul>
```

this'll show the source of my posts based on the custom fields I've made, and I just want them to show in the content-single.php file, I mean the single posts page. but they also showing in front page (index.php, content.php), I dont' want that. what conditional can I use and how? please help me with this cause I'm pretty weak in php and wp...

Comment: hmmm.... maybe I've missed it but I am not familiar with an `index-meta.php` template. What is that and how are you using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `is_single()` in a conditional statement.

```
<?php if( is_single() ){ ?>
  <ul>
    <li class="Source"><a>source:</a></li>
       <ul class="Source-Link">
           <li><a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'source-link', true); ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'source', true); ?></a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
<?php }?>
```

Be aware though that this will appear on any single page, meaning a single post page and a single page.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH BRO.
Your answer was really helpful
JUST WHAT I NEEDED
**THANKS A LOT AGAIN**